# Individual Table DisplayTag Settings

Tags: java, displaytag

I'm using displaytag to list information on my website and its working well. The problem I'm having is to do with the messages as defined in displaytag.properties. My website displays different types of information so for one displaytag table I may want the results banner to read:

"15 people found. Dislaying people 1 - 10."

Which I can set through displaytag.properties.

However, I have another table where I display a list of activities so in this case I want the banner to read:

"30 activities found. Displaying activities 1 - 10".

Is it possible for each displaytag table to have its own properties or do I have to use the catch-all "X items found" text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the values in displaytag.properties for individual tables

e.g. to change "people" to "activities"

```
<display:table....
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_name" value="activity" />
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.items_name" value="activities" />
    ...
</display:table>
```